# Custom CSS for a specific modal

Tags: css, angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I have more than one popup and I want to give one of them custom CSS and style. This is my code:

```
open(content,type?) {
    if(type) {
      this.modalService.open(content,{ windowClass: 'dark-modal',size:'sm'}).result.then((result) => {
        this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
      }, (reason) => {
        this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
      });
      return;
    }
    this.modalService.open(content,{ windowClass: 'dark-modal'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
```

Comment: maybe you can try using **panelClass** to add a custom class for the overlay pane, then from there you should be able to style it.

Comment: i`m trying to use the internal class and used it in global css file but all the modal (popup) take the same style i want to give the style for one popup just